# How to append to the state whenever a promise is resolved?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise

I am looking for a *whenever* kind of promise helper. Let's take the `Promise.All` function.
I have 4 promises. Two are instant speed. One is quick. One is slow. The slow promise takes 3 seconds to resolve.

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'slow');
});
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
  // here I want to setState()
  // this.setState({values})
});

// output: Array [3, "slow", "foo"]
```

When I run the code the `all` is going to wait for all promises (so 3seconds) then display the array. This follows the doc:

> The Promise.all() method takes an iterable of promises as an input, and returns a single Promise that resolves to an array of the results of the input promises. **This returned promise will resolve when all of the input's promises have resolved**, or if the input iterable contains no promises. It rejects immediately upon any of the input promises rejecting or non-promises throwing an error, and will reject with this first rejection message / error.

*emphasize is mine*

Now what I am looking for is a method who would returned a promise then resolve whenever one of the input's promises have resolved.

Something like:

```
Promise.whenever([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  // here I want to setState()
  // this.setState({values: this.state.values.concat([value])})
});
```

who would print

```
3
foo
slow
```

[promise all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: So in the end, you don't actually care about aggregation result, you just need those promises to be processed as they fulfill. In this case, the helper you wrote might be just the way to go.

Comment: Do you expect the `here I want to setState()` to be called multiple times? i.e. up to 3 times in your example, one for each resolved promise?

Comment: @raina77ow basically I am fetching a bunch of resource and I want to display them whenever I can.

Comment: @JaromandaX I would like to push to the state. Since the state is immutable, afaik I have to call setState multipletime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any native `whenever`, but you can basically build it with a `forEach` and a higher-order function.

```js
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000, 'slow');
});
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

const PromiseWhenever = (promises, action, rejectionAction) => {
  promises.forEach(promise => {
    promise.then(action).catch(rejectionAction);
  });
}

PromiseWhenever([promise1, promise2, promise3], value => console.log(value), () => console.error("failed"))
```

Now if you want `Promise.Whenever` you will have to edit the `Promise`'s prototype. Is it worth it though?

For the `setState`, it will works as you expected:

```
PromiseWhenever([promise1, promise2, promise3], value =>
    this.setState({ values: this.state.values.concat([value]) }, () => console.error("failed"))
```

Related to [How do I resolve multiple promises as they resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64641557/how-do-i-resolve-multiple-promises-as-they-resolve) and [setState inside promise.all() react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067237/setstate-inside-promise-all-react)

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with this approach as compared to `Promise.all` is that with `Promise.all`, state will be updated once, leading to only one re-render whereas with `PromiseWhenever`, you will have `N` state updates (N being the number of promises) and N re-renders.

Comment: How does this handle rejections?

Comment: Good point raised by @JaromandaX. I guess there needs to be a rejection handler passed to the `PromiseWhenever` function and `catch` method should be used as: `promise.then(action).catch(rejectionAction)` to handle the rejection of each individual promise separately.

Comment: Great point for the `rejectionAction`. I will add it.